# Type during array Initialization

Tags: c, unix

If in my program, I have this:

```
int arr[some_number];
```

What is the type of `some_number`?

1. Integer?
2. Unsigned integer?
3. Automatically determined (`long`, `unsigned long` etc.)

This might be a hypothetical question (assuming I can allocate as much memory as needed at compile time), just curious to know if type of `some_number` is always integer.

****EDIT
In case my language is not clear, on a system where sizeof(integer) is 2 bytes and I define array like:

int arr[65537] , will "65537" overflow and it is effectively, int arr[-1]?

Comment: To clarify, `some_number` is a numeric literal, right?

Answer (score 4):

some_number must either be an actual positive integer as in:-

```
int arr[1024]
```

or it can be a MACRO which resolves to a positive integer:-

```
#DEFINE some_number 1024
int arr[some_number]
```

As the interpretation is done at compile time and there are no program variable is used then there is no "type".

Comment: To be precise, `some_number` must be an *integer constant expression*.

Comment: @James Anderson. If I have a compiler where sizeof(integer) is 2 bytes. and I define array as int arr[65537], will it result in overflow?

Comment: @Oli, no, it must just be an expression of integral type, since C99 no need for it to be constant.

Comment: @Jens: Sure.  I'm talking about C "in general", though.

Comment: @Oli, C "in general" doesn't exist :)

Comment: @anon -- the maximum size of an array depends on the compiler implementation. And depends (mostly) on how much storage can  be addressed by the machines instruction set.

Answer (score 2):

By default in C, the type of a number is `int`. You can use the suffix `u` to make it an unsigned integer, the suffix `l` to make it a `long` (and with some compiler the suffix `ll` to make it a `long long`, ie. a 64-bit integer).

Answer (score 0):

Type of an expression doesn't depend on the context, so the type of `some_number` (`some_expression` actually) will be the same as if it was used not in the array definition. Another question is what types of expressions are allowed for designation of the array size.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is of type `size_t`, which can differ from one platform to another. It's unsigned, that's for sure. Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t).

Answer (score 0):

some_number must be TRUE  constant ,it cann't be variable.
for example

```
 main()
{
int a=1;
int kk[a]={1};
}
```

It would result an error saying

```
 variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

However we can not also use

```
int const a;
```

as array subscript beacuse const is not consider as true constant in C.

Comment: I think this is missleading. It must be a constant integer expression only if you want to initialize. If you don't as in the question a variable is perfectly valid since C99.

Comment: Yes its true only while initializing it throws an error but i am trying to cover more cases as anwser have already been given .That's all my intentions are.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this is a definition inside a function, `some_number` can be any integral expression with a strictly positive value. If it is non-constant, the beast is called *variable length array*, VLA.

If you place it in outer scope or make it `static`, it has to evaluate to something that is constant.